# How often can I repeat the road test in British Columbia?

Tags: canada, driving-license

Foreign drivers who want to convert their license to a Canadian one must pass the [Class 5 road test](http://www.icbc.com/driver-licensing/new-drivers/Pages/Get-your-full-licence.aspx) before they're issued a Canadian driving license. But the linked page fails to mention how often one can repeat that test - can I go in every single day until I get it right? Or is there a limit of some sort?

Comment: I'm seeing secondary sources that say 2 week wait.

Comment: Just for the record, licensing is provincial/territorial in Canada, so it varies from one province or territory to another.  Most provinces and territories have reciprocity with some countries, so it's not automatic that foreign drivers will need road testing, but many will.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie yes but in the case of BC most of the world's drivers are obligated to take the test. In comparison, my home country of Czech Republic converts licenses issued by any signatory of the 1949 or 1968 Road Conventions. Meanwhile any tourist can just drive in BC without any exams or preparation - go figure.

Comment: @JonathanReez BC has reciprocity with: AT AU FR DE EI JP NL NZ KR CH TW UK and US, plus Guernsey, Isle of Man and Jersey.  I know the list is gradually increasing in size.

Comment: @JimMackenzie the list is completely illogical as US driving licenses (who are the majority of those converting) are some of the easiest in the world to get. But the rest of the world is forced to waste time on bureucracy because ICBC apparently has very high standards.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think this is the forum to debate whether it's logical or illogical, but rather the forum to document what it *is*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the ICBC is vague on their online site, but numerous blogs mention that the waiting period between road tests is 2 weeks, as already mentioned by @mkennedy.